Can an uninitiated upasaka chant the kavacham of a deity?
As a Nitya upasaka suppose one desires to learn and chant a kavacham of a deity can he do it? The kavacham includes some Beeja mantras so will that produce any effects? Will the upasaka get any spiritual experience with it?
